# Why can I not get a properly formatted string from NSArray element?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to retrieve an attribute from my core data model and put the acquired string into the title of my navigation bar. I must be doing something wrong, as I cannot set my retrieved string as the title, yet I can set the title if I manually enter the string.

Here is how I am retrieving from Core Data:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Area" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

//set predicate
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@", self.area_id];

NSArray *area = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSString *area_name = [area valueForKey:@"name"];

NSString *test = @"test";

NSLog(@"%@",test);

NSLog(@"%@",area_name);
```

When I set the title using self.tabBarController.title = area_name; I get "NSArrayI stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" and it sets just fine when I set it to the test variable.

I also noticed that the NSLog for the variable test is "test" whereas the NSLog output for area_name is: ( "Single Area" )

Is this because of how I am retrieving my area_name from the array? Should I be using a dictionary instead? Forgive me for my ignorance, I'm fairly new to obj-c.

Thanks.

Comment: The 'area' array will hold all of the objects from the core data that conform to your predicate. You need to find the one you want and cast it to an object of it's class. You can then access it's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is mistake

```
NSString *area_name = [area valueForKey:@"name"];
```

`area` object is type of `NSArray` which contains `Area` objects.
So you need to get element from that array, and then read `name`.

```
Area *firstArea = [area firstObject];
NSString *area_name = firstArea.name;
NSLog(@"%@",area_name);
```

Comment: That did it. In several other areas of my project, I've gotten coredata and set strings using the method I showed and it has worked. e.g. cell.textLabel.text = area_name; Is it incorrect to do it this way and do I need to use the Area object each time?

Answer (score 0):

Change the predicate to this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier = %@", self.area_id];
```

I suppose than self.area_id is init correctly.