# NSString format issue - {( String )}

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am fetching data from core data and trying to print the name of the object at `valueForKey`. This has never caused me any trouble however when getting a direct object but the object I am getting is from an `NSSet` relationship.

When I print out the value I want, it displays in this format.

```
{(
     Bob Marley
)}
{(
    Jack Daniels
)}
etc...
```

I have used `NSString stringWithFormat`, I have tried `componentsSeperatedByString`, however neither of these work. If another question has been asked, I cannot find it on here. The issue is identical in a UILabel as well. Makes no difference where I print it.

Hopefully it's a simple issue.

My code for getting the value is.

```
//Company * company
//Employee is related in a many-many relationship
NSString * name = (NSString *)[self.company.contractor valueForKey:@"contractorName"];
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should use managed object to retrieve the data from core data that will help

Comment: I am using a fetchedResults controller to get the results, how would using managedObject make a difference? I have never had to use it as fetchedResults get's me what I have needed in the past.

Comment: you are getting array inside array{(
     Bob Marley
)} where {(Arry)}

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey`?

Comment: To get a specific name of an attribute in the Entity Contractor. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Doesn't it have a getter called `contractorName` which would allow the compiler to help with the type returned?  If so that would have avoided all of the confusion.

Comment: You are using `%@` to format an NSSet containing an NSArray.  You should properly fetch the values out of the set and the array.

Comment: In my fetchedResults I am fetching it using a predicate. I tried to place results in an array however didn't work correctly. Fortunately my accepted answer cured the issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe no because it's a many-many relationship. in a one-to-many relationship it does which makes life so much easier. Shame NSSet is not yet that bold. I am sure there is a good reason for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.company.contractor` is NSArray.

So you need to do

```
NSString * name = (NSString *)[[[self.company.contractor allObjects] firstObject] valueForKey:@"contractorName"];
```

Also refer to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838957/why-can-i-not-get-a-properly-formatted-string-from-nsarray-element/26839883#26839883)

Comment: Sorry, that is not correct. self.company.contractor is an NSSet not NSArray. So firstObject does not work. This is the message when trying your solution: "No visible @interface for 'NSSet' declares the selector 'firstObject'"